# convert continuous random variable to a discrete one for the given exponential distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, intuition, order-statistics

*I understand that the following question requires converting continuous r.v. to discrete r.v. But How can we get a PMF from the CDF of continuous distribution? It involves dividing continuous values into discrete ones.. Someone please give a solution to this question **with an intuition.***

Joe is waiting in continuous time for a book called The Winds of Winter to be released. Suppose that the waiting time T until news of the book’s release is posted, measured in years relative to some starting point, has PDF $\frac{1}{5}$ $e^{-\frac{t}{5}}$ for t>0 (and 0 otherwise); this is known as the Exponential distribution with parameter 1/5.

The news of the book’s release will be posted on a certain website. Joe is not so obsessive as to check multiple times a day; instead, he checks the website once at the end of each day. Therefore, he observes the day on which the news was posted, rather than the exact time T. LetX be this measurement, where X = 0 means that the news was posted within the ﬁrst day (after the starting point), X = 1 means it was posted on the second day, etc. (assume that there are 365 days in a year).

**Find the PMF of X.**

Comment: Corrected! thanks

Comment: Use the memorylessness property of the exponential distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The news about the book's release could go on the website anytime. So it is a continuous random variable. Joe check's it once at the end of the day. So essentially you have to map 0<=t<=1 to X=0 (quoting the question"Let X be this measurement, where X = 0 means that the news was posted within the ﬁrst day (after the starting point), X = 1 means it was posted on the second day, etc. ").

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out the convention used in the question. So X=0 means, the event happening anytime within 1st day..

Answer (score 1):

$$ P( X = 0) = P(T < 1) $$
$$ P(X = 1) = P(1 \le T < 2) = P(T < 2) - P(T < 1) $$

et cetera.

Now substitute the CDF of $T$ and calculate. Hopefully, you'll see a pattern emerge...

Comment: Thanks!Can you provide me links to understand the intuition behind P(X=1)=P(1≤T<2). I dont get how subtracting CDF(2) -CDF(1) will give PMF